# Ajax Request to netcore mvc app using IdentityServer redirects to authorization endpoint

Tags: ajax, http, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm developing an netcore MVC application which uses Ajax requests to POST data to the server.  I am using IdentityServer4 as my auth middleware.   The flow is when the application is launched with a URL of http://localhost:6002 it redirect to IdentityServer (localhost:6000).  The user logs in and is redirected to the main application which then works fine.

Ajax GET requests also work correctly.  I can observe a list of claims on the Get action in the controller (User.Identity.Claims).   However when I try a POST data from the server the request returns a 200 but from the Identity Server with Redirect=true

My call from the Javascript

```html
applyUpdate(modelData) {
  let that = this;
  fetch("http://localhost:6002/Client/Update/", {
   method: 'post',
   headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
   body: JSON.stringify(modelData)
   }
  ).then(function (response) {
   return response;
  }).then(function (outData) {
   alert("saved");
  });
 }
```

The response I receive is

```
{type: "cors", 
 url: "http://localhost:6000/account/login?returnUrl=%2Fc…%26x-client.., 
 redirected: true,
 status: 200, 
 ok: true}
```

I have enabled CORS on the applications as previously I was getting 405 issues.  What appears to be happening is when I call my controller action from Javascript a redirect is being performed to IdentityServer which is then returning to the client without ever actually executing my action.

My controller action looks like

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]      
    public async Task<JsonResult> Update([FromBody] MyVM myVM)
    {

    }
```

If I remove the [Authorize] attribute the method is reached however the value of User.Identity.Claims is always empty where in a HTTP Get it contains a list of all my claims.

Below is the relevant section for configuring IdentityServer from the Startup.cs file

```
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();         

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";                
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = identityUrl;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role",
                };

                options.ClientId = "my client";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;                  
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
            });
```

I am absolutely stumped at this behavior, any help would be greatly appreciated

### UPDATE

Bizarrely I am using the Javascript Fetch API to do the POST, when I swap it out of use Jquery Ajax it works perfectly so many it's the Fetch API that isn't managing the Redirect.  This call works fine

```
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'http://localhost:6002/Client/Update/',
            data: JSON.stringify(modelData),
            success: function success(msg) {
                alert("saved");
            },
            error: function error(xhr, data, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });
```

I didn't want to have to include a dependency Jquery

Comment: Use implicit flow? What does identity server log say?

Comment: My client is using HybridAndClientCredentials.  From the identity server logs it appears the request is beling authorized, I can see a message 'ValidatedAuthorizeRequest', however further in the logging it states 'User is not authenticated'.   HTTP GET to actions with the Authorize attribute work fine.   Do I need to pass the Access token in the header in some way?

Comment: Yes you need to pass the access token in the header and that's how IS authenticates the request. Are you saying your GET request is authorised without the access token in it?

Comment: Yes, GET works perfectly.  My application is an ASP MVC app that also has some javascript calls.  The user logs in using the MVC app.  I have the access token.  However I have tried to pass this in the authorization header but that makes no difference.  I'm adding the header like 'Authorization: Bearer ddaasdjk....'

Comment: sorry ignore what I said earlier; since you're using Hybrid flow, you shouldn't need to embed access token in your request. Based on your update, sounds like an issue from the client side; maybe compare the two requests (working and not working) and see what's the difference.